# Why and how disliking some divine laws is definitely an act of disbelief?

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh

There are some divine laws which are decreed, and I don’t like them because, I can’t do things I liked.

I have told about this to my Christian mother, and she told me that this means that I rise up against God if I don’t like some divine laws.

I have also asked my Muslim father regarding this, and he said that it is not an act of disbelief to dislike some divine laws.

And another Muslim told me 99% correct as my mother told me.

What confuses me is that, both they differently then one another, and I can’t tell who’s right or wrong, and I  don’t know if **by disliking some divine laws entails an act of disbelief? Yes or no? If yes, where’s the clear proof?**

Because, I’ve told my mother that I don’t have the intention to rise up against God, I’m a nobody to do this. And she insist by telling me that, even though you think that you do not have this intention, still it is an act of disbelief.

The reason for disliking some divine laws is because, it makes me feel uncomfortable, and I’m obligated to stay away from doing things I like.

Can someone please give me a concrete information regarding this issue? Because, I have this problem for long time.

I can’t tell why and how this is definitely an act of disbelief.

Answer (score 0):

You should base all your Judgements based on divine law, this is mentioned in chapter 5 of the Quran:

Lo! We did reveal the Torah, wherein is guidance and a light, by which the prophets who surrendered (unto Allah) judged the Jews, and the rabbis and the priests (judged) by such of Allah's Scripture as they were bidden to observe, and thereunto were they witnesses. So fear not mankind, but fear Me. And barter not My revelations for a little gain. Whoso judgeth not by that which Allah hath revealed: such are disbelievers. (44) And We prescribed for them therein: The life for the life, and the eye for the eye, and the nose for the nose, and the ear for the ear, and the tooth for the tooth, and for wounds retaliation. But whoso forgoeth it (in the way of charity) it shall be expiation for him. Whoso judgeth not by that which Allah hath revealed: such are wrong-doers. (45) And We caused Jesus, son of Mary, to follow in their footsteps, confirming that which was (revealed) before him in the Torah, and We bestowed on him the Gospel wherein is guidance and a light, confirming that which was (revealed) before it in the Torah - a guidance and an admonition unto those who ward off (evil). (46) Let the People of the Gospel judge by that which Allah hath revealed therein. Whoso judgeth not by that which Allah hath revealed: such are evil-livers. (47) And unto thee have We revealed the Scripture with the truth, confirming whatever Scripture was before it, and a watcher over it. So judge between them by that which Allah hath revealed, and follow not their desires away from the truth which hath come unto thee. For each We have appointed a divine law and a traced-out way. Had Allah willed He could have made you one community. But that He may try you by that which He hath given you (He hath made you as ye are). So vie one with another in good works. Unto Allah ye will all return, and He will then inform you of that wherein ye differ. (48) So judge between them by that which Allah hath revealed, and follow not their desires, but beware of them lest they seduce thee from some part of that which Allah hath revealed unto thee. And if they turn away, then know that Allah's Will is to smite them for some sin of theirs. Lo! many of mankind are evil-livers. (49)

The scripture you follow depends on your religion, but definitely the Quran instructs us not to base our Judgment on law other than divine law.

This probably ansewer part of your question whether you can become a disbelieve by not following divine laws, as this passage is only discussing following divine laws when judging.

But when you know these laws are from God, you should surrender to them even though you think that your way is better, because your creator knows what is best for you. Take for example drinking alcohol, some people say but drinking moderately is better than being too extreme and cutting it out completely, think about seriously, is there such a thing as drinking moderately. Say you have one glass, and you say to you self "I'm not drunk", then after you have had a few more, etc... until your too drunk to tell if you are drunk or not drunk.

Comment: No no, alcohol is definitely haram, no matter how much you drink. “It damages your brain”- said by many doctors. And I can feel that what they said is correct, and this is one of the main reasons for God To Ilegalize this.

Comment: @AlexA I can try to explain more but Allah know best what is the reason. Our religion is not based on what we can see to be right, it not based on logic and reason but faith. That  if we believe and  follow what Allah and his messenger brought we will be successful.

Comment: @AlexA There is a hadith, that once a man can to Allahs messenger(pbuh) and said I have only one slice of bread and me and my wife share this what should I do, Muhammad (pbuh) said get married, he came back and said I have two wife's  and one slice of bread, Muhammad (pbuh) said get married, he came back and said I have three wife's and one slice of bread, Muhammad (pbuh) said get married, he came back and said everything is fine now.  This man followed the command of Muhammad (pbuh) even though it does not make any sense.

Comment: @AlexA He had faith in Allah and the prophet (pbuh) (and thus was successful) and what is the opposite of faith, it is disbelief. Not to follow Allah commandment because your logic and reason does not agree with it, lacks faith in Allah, that he the all knowing all wise, all powerful etc... Also Islam teaches us to enter the religion wholeheartedly.

Comment: I’m just curious, why hasn’t he told him what he expected?

Comment: “Have you seen him who takes his low desires for his god? Are you a guardian over them? Or do you think that most of them hear or understand? They are but as the cattle; nay, they are farther astray from the path.” (The Holy Quran, 25:43–44.) Will be your answer.